# Serving static content GlassFish

Tags: tomcat, servlets, glassfish, war, web.xml

I want GlassFish to serve static content (jpg, css, js) which i've insterted in the project's war file.

I used the default servlet with tomcat and it works. Here is the declaration in web.xml:

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I've found some posts that tell how to do it but all refers to the use of external directory where the static content is saved. In my case I want the content to be in the war.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Do you have a custom/3rd party front controller servlet mapped on an overly generic `/*` pattern which thus also consumes static content?

Comment: I just want to servce static content in glassfish. Do you have an alternative?

Comment: Just drop those files in WAR and access them the usual way...? You don't need to configure a servlet for this at all. Glassfish (and Tomcat and all others!) automatically use their own default servlet for this. Only if you have a badly designed front controller servlet or filter mapped on `/*`, then you'd indeed need to explicitly configure the container's default servlet as demonstrated in your own question.

Comment: Here is the link : http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29550/why-the-difference-between-tomcat-and-tomcat7-regarding-servlet-mapping-and-defa

Comment: thanks body for th hint.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the images and css in Web-Inf folder and use getServletContext to use the contents.